# Rgd: Public Accessible Servers how to bring it to private

Tags: security, networking

i have a question.

I have a series of servers and inside contains my confidential data like codes and documentation.

The issue is this server is public accessible via the internet . What should i do to safeguard my codes?

I got servers like Active Directory, Mail Server,Web Server, File Directory Server , Development server , oracle server  and CIFS server .

What i think of is to use NAT, private ip address my servers, and only bring online those that I need it to be connect to the internet, e.g the web servers & mail server.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a firewall (I highly recommend [PF](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/)) between your WAN connection (the internet) and your LAN (your other servers). Use a private IP address space inside your LAN, and set up NAT to forward traffic received on the firewall's WAN interface (so from the internet) on port 80 to forward the request onto the web server (which now lives on the LAN) at port 80.  Repeat this exercise for each service that needs to be internet accessible.  Block all requests that you don't specifically authorize.  Make sure that the machine hosting your code is blocked from internet originated connections by the firewall.  If your network is small and the traffic to your servers is light, you don't need a very powerful machine to do your firewalling.